# how moq one of the interfaces in controller test

Tags: moq, .net-5, xunit, controller-tests

I have a controller class with 2 service interfaces: one is a post method of external URL and the second is a local repository. In the controller test class, I just want to moq the interface1, not the second. How can I do this? Or what is the best way to test this controller?

```
[Route("api/MyAPI")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyAPIController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Interface1 _interface1;
        private readonly Interface2 _interface2;

        public ProfitLossGrowthRateController(Interface1 interface1,
            Interface2 interface2)
        {
            _interface1= interface1;
            _interface2 = interface2;
        }

        [HttpPost("CodeAPI")]
        [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<Response>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Error), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Error), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<List<Response>> GetCodeAPIController
            (Request request)
        {
            var response1 = await _interface1.GetCodesByFilter(request);
            return await _interface2.GetGrowthRate(response1.Codes);
        }

    }
```

, meanwhile, in the first version of this controller when I don't have the first interface, I write my controller test like this and it  works correctly:

```
public class MyAPIControllerTest : IntegrationBaseTest
    {
        public MyAPIControllerTest ()
            : base(nameof(Repository))
        {
            DataProvider.InsertData<Data1>
                (Context, nameof(Data1));
        }


        [Theory]
        [InlineData("/api/MyAPI/CodeAPI")]
        public async Task GetGrowthRate(string url)
        {
            var request = new Request()
            {
                Filter = new List<string>() { "111" }
            };
            var content = await HttpHandler.PostURI<Request>(url, request, Factory);
            List<Response> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Response>>(content);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(response);
            Assert.Single(response);
            Assert.Equal("111", response[0].CompanyNationalCode);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hi,
If you test the controllers and especially with the integration test (you inherited from IntegrationBaseTest) I think, the best way is to use Web Application Factory and it will rise the startup.cs configuration then you can easily your controller with real DB and values ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0
                             
If the answer is no, you should use the unit test and not use the integration test. For that, you can use mocking and it can be a bit more difficult.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the hint. Yes, I'm currently using Web Application Factory. And, I want to use DB values, just mock one special method. I fixed it right now. I mock that method in the ConfigureWebHost Method of Factory class.